# How to get and set image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

This is my jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MEHhs/41/

This part is not working

```
//get the URL from image
        var imgUrl = document.getElementById("img").src;
```

Error message **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null** appears.

After research I couldn't find any better method. Can anyone help? Appreciate that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID of image is `picture` not `img`

Use

```
var imgUrl = document.getElementById("picture").src;
```

[DEMO without error](http://jsfiddle.net/MEHhs/42/)

As you are using jQuery,

```
$('#picture').click(function () {
    var picture = $('#picture');
    //get the URL from image
    var imgUrl = picture.prop('src');
    //if image 1 is displayed, change to image 2
    if (imgUrl == "http://www.mathe-fuer-antimathematiker.de/images/vorderseite.png") {
        picture.prop('src', 'http://www.mathe-fuer-antimathematiker.de/images/rueckseite.png');
    }
    //if image 2 is displayed, change to image 1
    else {
        picture.prop('src', 'http://www.mathe-fuer-antimathematiker.de/images/vorderseite.png');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/N5YTL/)

Additionally, use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.

Answer (score 1):

use "attr" attribute in jQuery.

Comment: She's selecting a non-existent element, how would `attr()` solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

`id` of img is `picture`.use:

```
var imgUrl = document.getElementById("picture").src;
```